# Random output in asynchronous function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have the following function and I need to add up the total cooking time of the array. The problem is sometimes I get undefined and sometimes I get the correct value, which is 65.
Anyone have any idea whats going on? Thank you for your time.

```
function cookingTime(cook) {
  console.log(cook);
}
const arr = ['meat', 'carbs', 'veg'];

function cookDinner(arr, cb) {
  let mealsProcessed = 0;
  arr.forEach(meal => {
    cookMeat((err, meat) => {
      meat;
      mealsProcessed++;
      cookCarbs((err, carbs) => {
        carbs;
        mealsProcessed++;
        cookVeg((err, veg) => {
          veg;
          mealsProcessed++;
          if (mealsProcessed === arr.length) {
            let result = meat + carbs + veg;
            cb(result)
          };
        });
      });
    });
  });
};


console.log(cookDinner(arr, cookingTime));
```

And here are the functions I am calling back to:

```
 function cookMeat (cb) {
   setTimeout(function () {
       cb(null, 30); 
    }, Math.random()*1500);
}

function cookCarbs (cb) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        cb(null, 20); 
     }, Math.random()*100);
}

function cookVeg (cb) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        cb(null, 15); 
     }, Math.random()*1000);
}
```

Comment: You're looping through an array that you don't seem to use, and calling `cookMeat` once for each element in that array, so in total you cookMeat, cookCarbs, and cookVegs, 3 times each for a total of 9 `mealsProcessed`.  For that reason `mealsProcesses` will usually be much larger than `arr.length` when you get to your if statement and you don't call the callback at all.

Comment: You're seeing undefined because you also log the return value of `cookDinner` which is always `undefined` since it has no return statement.

Comment: If you remove the if statement and just always call the callback from `cookVeg` you will see 65 logged three times; once for each element in your array.

Comment: I'd write a full answer, but I'm on mobile so someone else can or you even can write it and accept it yourself if the comments I've made have helped you enough to do that.

Comment: @Paulpro hmm, I did managed to get 65 logged three times before.
I am trying to follow your advice for now, but no result, I will keep trying and thank you for the help.